# Delete a dom element using a button within it, vanilla JS

Tags: javascript, dom, button, event-listener, removechild

I am quite new to this and have been looking for a way to make a 'delete' button with the assigned eventListener to remove the element it relates to(li).

I don't know JS as well yet, so it might not be the best way to do that, but that's what I have so far:

A simple HTML

```
<h1>The List</h1>
<ul>
  <li>Delete me<button id="del">x</button></li>
  <li>Delete me too<button id="del">x</button></li>
</ul>
```

I would like to make each 'del' button to delete its parent - 'li' where this button is nested.. and I want to write a reusable function.

I can sort of get an idea that I need to "make the click function to delete child(li) of parent(ul)". How can I connect specific 'li' with the 'button' nested in it?

I was also thinking maybe be loop through to give it an unique id or a number.. I am a bit lost here, could you please suggest me what can be done, considering I'm really new and cannot do any frameworks yet, just want to be able to do it in JS.

I made this to try, but that's too specific, eventually it needs to reusable for any of them without knowing the order:

```
const parent = document.getElementsByTagName('ul')[0];
const child = parent.getElementsByTagName('li')[0];
const del = document.getElementById('del');

function removeMe() {
  parent.removeChild(child);
}

del.addEventListener('click', removeMe);
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you want to add the same logic on multiple buttons you should use `classes` instead of `ids`. The ID should be unique. With [Element.closest()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest) you can find the closest parent from where the click happened until it finds a node that matches the provided selector string. Read the comments inside the code sample here

```js
 // deleteButtons is will be an array of buttons
const deleteButtons = document.querySelectorAll('.del');

deleteButtons.forEach( button => {
  // add the event listener to each button
  button.addEventListener('click', removeMe); 
});

function removeMe() {
   // this is the button
   // from the button you want to move up in DOM 
   // and find the closes <li> to remove
   this.closest('li').remove(); 
}
```

```html
<h1>The List</h1>
<ul>
  <li>Delete me<button class="del">x</button></li>
  <li>Delete me too<button class="del">x</button></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

As others remarked, an element id [should be unique in the document](https://www.deque.com/blog/unique-id-attributes-matter/).

Use [event delegation](https://javascript.info/event-delegation) and use a [data-attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes) to recognize the button that should activate deletion.

```js
document.addEventListener('click', evt => {
  const origin = evt.target;
  if (+origin.dataset.deleteparent) {
    origin.closest("li").remove();
  }
});

/* 
  --explained--
  const origin = evt.target;
                 ^ where did the click originated?
  if (+origin.dataset.deleteparent)
      ^       ^ only if the button contains data-deleteparent attribute
      ^ convert data-attribute value to Number. 
        If it's not there, or 0, nothing will happen
    origin.closest("li").remove();
           ^ parent li   ^
                         ^ remove it
  }
*/
```

```css
button[data-deleteparent] { color: red; border: none; background-color: transparent; cursor: pointer}
```

```html
<h1>The List</h1>
<ul>
  <li>Delete me <button data-deleteparent="1">&#x2718;</button></li>
  <li>Delete me too <button data-deleteparent="1">&#x2718;</button></li>
  <li>Delete me not <button>Do not delete</button></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Even though you are using a different approach, this would delete all `<li>` elements which contain a button. you do not check for the `id` which is not unique but and `id` should be unique. sorry this needs a downvote

Comment: Adjusted the answer.

Comment: `.parentNode.parentNode`, edit a bit the HTML, see the application fail, than go to JS, edit i.e: as: `.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode` refresh and it works! `closest` should always be the preferred way to make JS as flexible as possible.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan Fine. Wanted to demonstrate DOM traversal here, but hey, `closest` is ok too.

Answer (score -1):

Just use `parentElement` property of DOM node.
Also, as mentioned above - you should use `class`es instead of id in your case, because `id` must be unique.

```js
const buttons = document.querySelectorAll('.rm-button');

function rmParent() {
   this.parentElement.remove();
}

buttons.forEach(button => {
  button.addEventListener('click', rmParent);
});
```

```html
<h1>The List</h1>
<ul>
  <li>Delete me<button class="rm-button">x</button></li>
  <li>Delete me too<button class="rm-button">x</button></li>
</ul>
```